# How to Create a Key Store for Three Key in Java Swing using getKeyStroke()?

Tags: java, swing

I want to set a *Triple Key Accelerator* ( which means I need a *Triple Key KeyStroke* ) for a **Menu Item** in Java Swing, specifically, **Shift + Ctrl + N**. My way of setting a key stroke: `menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK))`, this will return a key stroke, **Ctrl + N**. Is there a way to create a *Triple Key KeyStroke* so that I can set it as a Menu Item Accelerator. I have read this part of Oracle Documentation ([Oracle JDK 16 Documention](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html)) but it did not helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read this part of Oracle Documentation:

```
static KeyStroke getKeyStroke​(int keyCode, int modifiers)
```

The key is that the second parameter is "modifiers" (plural).

So to specify multiple modifiers you "and" the the two modifiers:

```
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK + KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, true);
```

Or, using the following method:

```
public static KeyStroke getKeyStroke​(String s)
```

You would use:

```
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift control N");
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed it the word 'modifiers' is plural but IDK how to define multiple of them. 